# When is a subspace of the cohomology of a smooth projective scheme on $k$ a motive?

Tags: cohomology, motives, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth projective scheme over a number field $k$, and $V_{p}$ (resp. $V_{\text{dR}}, V_{\text{B}}$) a sub-space of $H_{et,p}^{\ast}(X)$ (resp. $H^{\ast}_{\text{dR}}(X), H^{\ast}_{\text{B} } (X)$) such that $V_{p}$, $V_{\text{dR}}$ and $V_{\text{B}}$ are isomorphic up to tensor and comparison isomorphism. It is also assumed that they are endowed with Galois action (resp. filtration, Hodge structure) which correspond by comparison to isomorphisms.

I would like to consider rational equivalence over cycles, but if you have an answer to the following question for another relation feel free to consider that relation instead.

**Question** Do we know a condition (necessary? sufficient?) on $V_{p}$, $V_{\text{dR}}$ and $V_{\text{B}}$ such that they are the realization of a pure motive? When they are realisation of a motive $V$, what are its relations with $H^{\ast}(X)$? Does anyone have a reference where this kind of "submotives" is studied?

Comment: Probably, the standard conjectures predict that any Galois submodule of V_p lifts to a pure motif (and then you can envoke some more conjectures to obtain a Chow motif:)). On the other hand, you need the Standard Conjecture C to prove that the whole H^k(X) comes from a pure motif.

Comment: Yes the $H^{k}$ was a mistake, I'm focusing on cohomology concentrated in one degree for some times so I forgot that projectors are not known to be cycles :) I just make the changes. For the other part of your comment however, I really don't see which part of the standard conjectures are telling us this.. could you be a little bit more precise please?

Comment: Actually, the standard conjectures imply that a subspace of V_p lifts to a motif if and only if it is its direct summand (as a Galois representation). Possibly, this assumption is not vacuous (since the whole V_p is not necessarily semi-simple); I don't know.

Comment: And if you have a subobject in the mixed realization of $X$ (as defined by A. Huber; probably she followed Jannsen and Deligne) then it is a direct summand since one can apply a simple polarization argument. Hence any subobject of this sort should lift to a pure motif.